# How do I print the distinct pairs of the target sum of the following program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the following program, I am getting the output in which the pair is repeating, could you please help me with how do I print only the unique pairs?

The following program is to print the pairs to the target sum. I have to get only "1 and 4" and "2 and 3" as the output. I should not get "4 and 1" in the output.

```
def printPairs(arr, n, sum): 
        for i in range(0, n ): 
            for j in range(i + 1, n ): 
                if (arr[i] + arr[j] == sum): 
                    print("", arr[i], " and ", arr[j], "", sep = "") 
    arr = [5,1,2,3,4,1,5] 
    n = len(arr) 
    sum = 5
    printPairs(arr, n, sum)

Current Output:
1 and 4
2 and 3
4 and 1

Required Output:
1 and 4
2 and 3
```

Comment: dont  just print..save it somewhere like in a set and check if you have seen the combination before

Answer (score 0):

Store the pairs in a set:

```
    def printPairs(arr, n, sum):
        pairs = set() 
        for i in range(0, n ): 
            for j in range(i + 1, n ): 
                if (arr[i] + arr[j] == sum):
                    if arr[i] in pairs or arr[j] in pairs:
                         continue
                    else:
                         print("", arr[i], " and ", arr[j], "", sep = "") 
                         pairs = pairs + {arr[i] + arr[j]}
    arr = [5,1,2,3,4,1,5] 
    n = len(arr) 
    sum = 5
    printPairs(arr, n, sum)

Current Output:
1 and 4
2 and 3
4 and 1

Required Output:
1 and 4
2 and 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def printPairs(arr, n, sum):
    seen = []
    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            if (arr[i] + arr[j] == sum):
                if not arr[i] in seen and not arr[j] in seen:
                    seen.append(arr[i])
                    seen.append(arr[i])
                    print("", arr[i], " and ", arr[j], "", sep="")
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest one I could think of using set. Save the elements as tuples to achieve maximum performance of O(1)

```
def printPairs(arr, n, sum): 
    my_set=set()
    for i in range(0, n ): 
        for j in range(i + 1, n ): 
            if (arr[i] + arr[j] == sum) and tuple(sorted([arr[i],arr[j]])) not in my_set: 
                    my_set.add(tuple(sorted([arr[i],arr[j]])))
                    print("", arr[i], " and ", arr[j], "", sep = "")
```

For further improving the performance I'd sort the array first and would check if the element is already greater than the sum if yes then I would use continue or break as per the situation. Here is the example

```
def printPairs(arr, n, sum): 
    arr.sort()
    my_set=set()
    for i in range(0, n ): 
        if i>sum: # Check before going inside the inner loop
            continue
        for j in range(i + 1, n ): 
            if (arr[i] + arr[j] > sum):
                break; # break if the sum of elements is greater than expected sum
            if (arr[i] + arr[j] == sum) and tuple(sorted([arr[i],arr[j]])) not in my_set: 
                    my_set.add(tuple(sorted([arr[i],arr[j]])))
                    print("", arr[i], " and ", arr[j], "", sep = "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.combinations`:

```py
import itertools
def printPairs(arr, n, total): 
    combinations = itertools.combinations(arr, 2)
    viewed = []
    for a, b in combinations:
        if a + b == total:
            if (a, b) not in viewed and (b, a) not in viewed:
                viewed.append((a, b))
                print(a, 'and', b)


arr = [5,1,2,3,4,1,5] 
n = len(arr) 
sum = 5
printPairs(arr, n, sum)
```

Some observations:

- you don't need to pass `n` (the length of the array), you can simply get it from `len(arr)`.
- You should use a different than `sum` because it is a built-in function

You can also use a `set` to track the combinations without repetition:

```py
import itertools
def printPairs(arr, n, total): 
    combinations = itertools.combinations(arr, 2)
    viewed = set()
    for a, b in combinations:
        if a + b == total:
            if (a, b) not in viewed and (b, a) not in viewed:
                viewed.add((a, b))
                print(a, 'and', b)


arr = [5,1,2,3,4,1,5] 
n = len(arr) 
sum = 5
printPairs(arr, n, sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this as the first thing in the function:

```
arr = list(set(arr))
n = len(arr)
```

set() converts your 'arr' list into a set, all duplicates are removed

list() converts the resulting set back into a list

This also makes 'n' argument redundant though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply.  Remove the duplicates and sort the list.
Then iterate through the list until you get to half the target value.
For each list element, see whether the needed number is in the list.

**O(N)** solution.

```
arr = [5,1,2,3,4,1,5]    
target = 5

# Clean the input: dedup and sort
arr = sorted(set(arr))

# For each element in the lower half of the list,
#   see whether the needed amount is also in the list.
for pos, value in enumerate(arr):
    need = target - value
    if need < value:
        break
    if need in arr:
        print(value, "and", need)
```

Output:

```
1 and 4
2 and 3
```